# Replacing string between double quotes with a environment variable value in sed

Tags: regex, sed, double-quotes

All,
I have a C header file, let's called it **test.h**, that looks like this:

```
#define KNOWN_STRING "replace_this"
```

I want to replace this with the value of an environment variable called **$test** (let's assume the value is "new_value"). This is how I set it:

```
setenv test new_value
```

So that the test.h will look like this:

```
#define KNOWN_STRING "new_value"
```

I tried this sed command:

```
sed -i -E 's/KNOWN_STRING "(.+)"/KNOWN_STRING "'"$test"'"/g test.h
```

The reasoning here is to match whatever (zero or more?) character between the double quotes. But I got: Unmatched '.

I also tried this:

```
sed -i -E "s/(KNOWN_STRING.+)(\".+)(\") /\2$test\3/g" test.h
```

But I got: Unmatched ".

I guess my regular expression is not correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your regex is fine.  Count the number of single quotes.  It is odd.  Just add a single quote after the `/g`.

Comment: In a regexp zero or more is `.*`, you wrote `.+` which means one or more. The parens aren't doing anything useful in `/KNOWN_STRING "(.+)"/`

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

You need to make the quotes match up.  The following, for example, works:

```
$ sed -E 's/KNOWN_STRING "(.+)"/KNOWN_STRING "'"$test"'"/g' test.h
#define KNOWN_STRING "new_value"
```

When you are satisfied that you have a statement that does what you want, you can add back the `-i` option for modifying the file in-place.

Note that this approach will fail if the variable `test` contains any unescaped sed-active characters.

#### Using awk

Awk can do something very similar but without the potential pitfalls of active characters:

```
$ awk -v test="$test" '{gsub(/KNOWN_STRING ".+"/, "KNOWN_STRING \"" test "\"")} 1' test.h
#define KNOWN_STRING "new_value"
```

With GNU awk (sometimes called gawk), the file can be changed in place:

```
awk -i inplace -v test="$test" '{gsub(/KNOWN_STRING ".+"/, "KNOWN_STRING \"" test "\"")} 1' test.h
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I've tried the sed command and it works. I guess I only missed the closing single quote. A follow up question: For this type of simple file manipulation, which one is more commonly used? sed or awk? I understand sed and awk is pretty much standard in any *nix system, but I just want to make sure that any tools we put out there follow common practice.

Comment: @irssquare Awk and sed each shine in their own domain.  Both are required by POSIX and both part of common practice.  In general, awk is better at handling arithmetic and complex logic (neither of which you need here) and variables (which, in this case, are helpful),  Unless you are sure that `test` will never contain sed-active characters, I would use awk for this case.